# AssertionError: Root package must be initialized

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I open my Kotlin project on another computer in Android Studio and met error in Event Log:

> AssertionError: Root package must be initialized

```
Root package must be initialized
java.lang.AssertionError: Root package must be initialized
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ResolveSession.getAllPackages(ResolveSession.java:329)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.lazy.ResolveSession.forceResolveAll(ResolveSession.java:350)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.references.BuiltInsReferenceResolver$2.run(BuiltInsReferenceResolver.java:121)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:872)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.references.BuiltInsReferenceResolver$3.run(BuiltInsReferenceResolver.java:141)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:56)
```

Project main structure:

[image]

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "taskmoney"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    local.java.srcDirs += 'src/local/kotlin'
    }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//dependencies list
}

buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '0.12.1230'
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

So, can't open any .kt file.

Guess I miss something simple... Thanks

Comment: This looks very much like a bug, and the best place for it would be our issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: @Ardi, did you create an issue in YouTrack, if so what is the issue number to track progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because of the version of your Android Studio IDE. I had the same issue when I was using 1.2 and after I upgraded to 1.5, problem solved.